# How to receive a res.send(req.body) when send back to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send the req.body on a POST request route back to the function executing the POST request.

the req.body is like this `{ username: 'aa', password: 'ss' }`

i am using a function to post and after posting a want to work with the response.

Using res.sendStatus(200) or res.sendStatus(401) i can access it like this

```
post('/login', { username, password })
    .then(({ status }) => {
      if (status === 200) {alert('login success'); window.location.href = "/about"}
      else alert('login failed')
    })
```

how can i access the username  using `then()` when responding with `res.send(req.body)` or `res.json(req.body)`

i tried `.then(({ username }) => {alert(username)})` and get undefined error

Comment: Can't you just `username` already defined in your request on the client?

Comment: @Li357 i want to send multiple data back thats why i try to send req.body

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Some basic debugging by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network would also help. There you can see what was actually sent and returned

Comment: server side `res.status(200).json({username: req.body.username});` . Client side `.then(({ status, username }) => {`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `fetch` api, you will have your response json when you call `json()` on the response object.

```
post('/login', { username, password })
  .then(({ status, json }) => {
    const responseJSON = json();
    const { username } = responseJSON; // all your data will be in this object
    if (status === 200) {alert('login success'); window.location.href = "/about"}
    else alert('login failed')
})
```

If you are using `axios`, you will have your response json in `data` object.

```
post('/login', { username, password })
  .then(({ status, data }) => {
    const responseJSON = data;
    const { username } = responseJSON; // all your data will be in this object
    if (status === 200) {alert('login success'); window.location.href = "/about"}
    else alert('login failed')
})
```

Comment: I was wondering the same. I believe this answers what the OP was asking. Not sure what the downvoter was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you can get `username` first.

```
post('/login', { username, password })
.then(response => {
    responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(responseJSON);
});
```